# How to convert smalldatetime retrieved from database back to smalldatetime to be reposted to the database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a form that takes an item from my database of "smalltime" type and I would like to re add this to another database as "smalldatetime" However the problem i ran into is that is reading my item a string. I am not sure what approach to take to convert this but here is what i have so far:

```
var checkOutDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ddlCheckOutDate.Text);
sl.ReqCheckOutDate = checkOutDate;
```

Can anyone help me over this hurdle?

Comment: If you are moving it from one DB to another why is there a text box involved?

Comment: Further, why is *text* involved at all? All you should need is `DateTime` or *possibly* `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Well I take it from one database and use in a dropdownlist. The user choose one. That one i would like to put in the other database @JonSkeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are reporting is due to Culture difference. You are using US formatted date and the current culture is set to UK or similar so it thinks you are using Day/Month/Year and which makes 12/14/2013 is Day=12 Month=14 Year=2013 and therefore invalid.

Using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) will allow you to control the exact conversion of your date:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateAsText = "12/14/2012 12:00:00 PM";
DateTime something = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsText, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", provider);
```

Comment: Well @Belogix I am trying to capture it as a smalldatetime type. Which would just be the date and the time as it is taken from the database

Comment: Changed code as guessing you are trying to read, edit and write? What error / issue are you encountering on the write back?

Comment: This is what I get back when i test the form "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: OK, so now we are on to the real issue! If you debug what is the value of txtDateTime.Text (or whatever your control is called)?

Comment: its a dropdown list so the user only needed to choose an option 12/14/2012 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Ah, OK so it looks like an international issue. I.e. It is saying that 14 is not a valid month. I'll update my answer shortly...

Comment: @Robertpurpose - OK, the code and answer now reflect your issue and hopefully answers you problem fully.